Как соединить консольное приложение с миграциями с приложением .Net MAUI
Не получилось создать миграции в самом проекте .Net MAUI, выдаёт такую ошибку:
Startup project 'FieldsMob' targets platform 'Android'. The Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools don't support this platform. See https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-pmc-tfms for more information.
Нашла решение этой проблемы, что можно миграции создать в отдельном консольном приложении и потом использовать это приложение в основном проекте для подключения и работы с базой данных на SQL Server. Все необходимые пакеты Nuget установлены(версия 8.0)
Код в консольном приложении Migration:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

 
public class ProcessingIndustry
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID_PI { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Script { get; set; }
}
public class ExtractiveIndustry
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

    public int ID_EI { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Script { get; set; }
}
public class Users
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID_user { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Patronymic { get; set; }
    public string Access { get; set; }

}
public class Authorizate
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID_authorizate { get; set; }
    public int ID_user { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public int Password { get; set; }

    public virtual Users Users { get; set; }

}
public class Types_of_fields
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID_types { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Areas
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID_area { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Minerals
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID_mineral { get; set; }
    public int ID_EI { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Raw_material_quality { get; set; }
    public string Suitability { get; set; }

}
public class Fields
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID_field { get; set; }
    public int ID_mineral { get; set; }
    public int ID_types { get; set; }
    public int ID_area { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Year_of_study { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Conditions_of_exploitation { get; set; }
    public string Stocks { get; set; }
    public string Develop { get; set; }
    public string DevelopNot { get; set; }

    public virtual Areas Areas { get; set; }
    public virtual Minerals Minerals { get; set; }
    public virtual Types_of_fields Types_of_fields { get; set; }

}
public class FieldsContext : DbContext
{
    public FieldsContext(DbContextOptions dbContextOptions) : base(dbContextOptions)
    {

    }

    public virtual DbSet<Areas> Areas { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Authorizate> Authorizate { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ExtractiveIndustry> ExtractiveIndustry { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Fields> Fields { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Minerals> Minerals { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ProcessingIndustry> ProcessingIndustry { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Types_of_fields> Types_of_fields { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }    
   
}

В основном проекте .Net MAUI в json файле прописана строчка подключения к бд, добавила приложение Migration в основной проект
Структура

public static class MauiProgram
  {
      public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
      {
          var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
          builder
              .UseMauiApp<App>()
              .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
              {
                  fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                  fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
              });

          builder.Services.AddDbContext<FieldsContext>(options =>
          {
          options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("FieldsConnectionString")??
              throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection 'FieldsConnectionString' is not found"));
      });

Но при подключении миграций из консольного приложения выдает ошибку
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --project "C:\Users\Veronika\source\repos\dpo\FieldsMob\Migration.csproj" --startup-project "C:\Users\Veronika\source\repos\dpo\FieldsMob\Migration.csproj" --msbuildprojectextensionspath "C:\Users\Veronika\source\repos\dpo\FieldsMob\Migration.csproj"

Ошибка:

MSBUILD : error MSB1003: СѓРєР°Р¶РёС‚Рµ РїСЂРѕРµРєС‚ РёР»Рё С„Р°Р№Р»
СЂРµС€РµРЅРёСЏ. РўРµРєСѓС‰РёР№ СЂР°Р±РѕС‡РёР№ РєР°С‚Р°Р»РѕРі РЅРµ
СЃРѕРґРµСЂР¶РёС‚ РїСЂРѕРµРєС‚ РёР»Рё С„Р°Р№Р» СЂРµС€РµРЅРёСЏ. Unable
to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an SDK-style project. If
you're using a custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or
MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the
--msbuildprojectextensionspath option.

Новичок на данной платформе,тяжеловато понять как исправить проблему, что делаю не так

Довольно интересная статья по этой теме с исходным кодом на GitHub. А вообще, ИМХО, клиент не должен применять миграции, это задача сервера. Если ваше приложение напрямую работает с базой, то это огромная дыра в безопасности.
